# Overflow-wrap property is not working properly

Tags: html, css

By default , it there's a long word at the end of a line which cannot fit in the remaining space , it's automatically shifted to a new line.

This property is used in such cases to make break the word letting it take the remaining space as much it can before shifting rest part of the long word to another line.
(At least from what I understood).

I gave this property a try but it doesn't seem to work well for some reason.

```css
div {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
This is the first time I've seen the word Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis. It's a long one
</div>
```

The longer word in my example instead of breaking down just normally shifts to new line ignoring this property.

After a little bit of googling, I found a property which works similarly: `word-wrap: break-word;`. So I replaced overflow wrap with it. It didn't work so I kept both of them together, but that still didn't worked.

To better understand my question ( if according to you my output is fine ) then please check this

Edit - my issue is fixed but the explanation i had given for this property above is wrong
The old name of this property is word-wrap

And this being a property with new name , i wouldn't anyone to get wrong info through my question
so here's a correct example and explaination of what this property does which i wrote  - https://del.dog/qeraracita.coffeescript

Comment: your css is wrong. `.div` is looking for a element with a className of div. remove the dot and it works fine

Comment: @rlemon i am sorry. That was a typo. My original codes didn't had it still its not working. You can check the output on js bin  .. i updated it still not working

Comment: overflow-wrap is still working correctly, hyphens is not. is that your question?

Comment: Your demo is working just fine for me.

Comment: @rlemon both are both working. You can check Output

Comment: I am checking. [the word breaks are happening correctly](https://i.imgur.com/ehQnNCw.png) however hyphens are not. Note: mdn does touch on this. hyphens is browser / language specific and may not be consistent.

Comment: also, if both are working.. what is the actual question?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17lc3Z7HPSsaR_OOiXa325lVTAdw8b7Y4/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: wait a minute, do you expect it to just break up long text without that text exceeding the container? because that's not how it works at all.

Comment: @rlemon It does seem to be the idea...? It works like that here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/

Comment: Second `<div>` tag is wrong - should be `</div>`, although that won't change anything I'm sure.

Comment: @rlemon well that's not a default behavior. You are right. But this property is supposed to do it. Hence the value - break-word in it's value

Comment: What is the difference between your code and https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/? Try adding `word-wrap: break-word` to your css?

Comment: ohh I see you want it to break that word earlier than it does. I get the problem now.

Comment: For everyone else confused (maybe I'm the only one) https://jsbin.com/lowayipelu/1/edit?html,css,output here is a better depiction of the problem with expected behaviour and actual.

Comment: @rlemon But why does your jsbin work and his code doesn't...?

Comment: my 'expected' has a line break element in it. I've manually adjusted it to look how I believe OP wants the break to occur. I don't think this is something we can do automagically. adding in the breaks manually (@Fleflis's answer) is probably the best approach.

Comment: But your "actual" section displays correctly.

Comment: @Stefan even his isn't Perfect. There is spacing on the second and third line even .. If you want to see a perfect solution check this pic - https://drive.google.com/file/d/17m_SS0pFy9Di249TFOukXfWfsi0pkZ0x/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Yes, that's the link I gave you earlier on in the comments.  I just don't see why yours doesn't work.

Comment: @Stefan i know right , ideally it should work.  Just a normal css property.  I will keep trying.  Trial and error. Will update here once i find solution

Comment: @rlemon btw the explanation i have given for this property in question is wrong.  I had not fully understand it.  Sorry for being wrong Earlier. But that's how we learn.  If you wanna look what exactly it does . You may read this i just wrote - https://del.dog/qeraracita.coffeescript

Answer (score 3):

The example you are using as your "proper break" from CSS-Tricks (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/) has a non breaking space between 'Word' and the long word, making it a single word to break up, hence the difference you see between where the word breaks in your code and the example.

```
<p>This is the first time I've seen the word&nbsp;Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis. It's a long one.</p>
```

remove that extra non breaking space and the word break happens how it does in your demo. https://codepen.io/rlemon/pen/MWgxXmK

so to solve your problem, add back in the non breaking space and let it treat those two words as one.

Comment: OK - the trick has been discovered. Still strange that it happens like that, though.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/188SFMAsActQ8bMKC7hD3dAxXkY0HpFta/view?usp=drivesdk.   Output in jsbin having the exact same codes from css tricks. Wonder why there is so much spacing in the seocnd line

Comment: @rlemon i fixed it in my jsbin now    The golden rule of this property is.  Find which line has space left on right which you want to to occupied.  Then  whichever word is the last word of that line add &nbsp; before it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're applying these properties to all elements with the`.div` class, not the `div` element itself. Remove the dot ('.') on the CSS selector.

If it still doesn't work, use the HTML entitie `&shy;`. Its an hypen that doesn't appear until the word is broken. This is great, so you can tell the browser where it should break (same as `<wbr>`, but with hypen).

Example:

```
<div> 
This is the first time I've seen the word 
&shy;ultra&shy;microscopic&shy;silico&shy;volcano&shy;coniosis. It's a long one.
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the unexpected behavior.
Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/aquabums/pen/aboMGrm) demonstrating overflow-wrap.

HTML

```
<div>
<p>This is the first time I've seen the word Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis. It's a long one</p>
<div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: That's working well indeed. Although i still wonder why it don't work in my codes. The apparent difference is that you wrapped text inside a p and gave overflow-wrap to p instead of div

Comment: Also, another note is that your closing div tag is <div> and not </div>

Comment: @Badal Singh Changing your wrapper to `p` makes no difference. It's a mystery indeed.

Comment: I see no difference between this and the original demo (besides the paragraph adding padding and squishing the content). The word break still happens in the same spot if you remove the padding on the paragraph.

Comment: For future reference, can someone tell me why this was downvoted?

Comment: @aqua well i don't see anything wrong as such in your answer for it be downvoted  .i don't know who did it but i will upvote it to make it even from -1 atleast.

Comment: Maybe you were downvoted because your solution actually suffers from the same problem as the OP's (I verified by using different widths in your solution)  and also because you did not show why the OP's solution did not work, which is what he wanted to find out.